# Existing or New Build Environment sets using Jenkins UI are Getting reset/deleted after Jenkins Restore

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I Have restored jenkins, by copying all xml and config files (job, plugins, all XML). I found one issue after restoration. When I configure a freestyle job and set some build environment, after saving the configuration it does not make any change in job configuration. Strange It did not say any error and showed a message it saved, but it is not.

After saving the configuration and going back and checking my saved configuration, I found that No changes were made. What can be the reason ??

I have tried setting the encoding format of the job config file to utf-8 but seems like it does not matter.
I also restarted Jenkins, but it did not help,
Tried upgrading the specific plugin which shows under the Build Environment Section of the job configuration, but it does not work.
I have also checked the permissions of config.xml files the same as before backup

Though All the options are showing and a user can configure, the moment I save in the hope that it is already saved, it actually not. When I review that build environment section, I see no changes made as in the attached screenshot.
Can someone Help me resolve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRbkY.png)

Comment: If this is on a new Jenkins machine, perhaps your config.xml is carrying over permissions from your old Jenkins machine and does not allow the user of your new Jenkins to write to the config.xml. Make sure your config.xml for this particular job has the correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but No, it's not the permission issue. Because even I create new Job, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: And it's the jenkins docker image.